# Is it possible to use a DRM driver from kernel space?

Tags: c, kernel-module, drm

I would like to program a driver that creates a fbdev device but internally use the drm driver (something like a fbdev to drm bridge). The target is to use `mplayer -vo fbdev`, but present custom fbdev that use the drm functions, because I need to do some stuff on the video playback when vblank happend (and that functionality is not available in fbdev). I was looking for a related projects but couldn't find nothing, I look for documentation but is crazy huge and not concise in this topic.

I was playing with the drm driver from userspace and it is easy and well documented, but, when you want to open the drm device from the kernel (like from your kernel module) space is another thing.

The first part of my question is:
Is possible to open a drm device from kernel space?

And in case of being affirmative:
Can anyone recommend a good starting point for this job? Project from github or documentation page (please, not kernel.org or freedesktop.org).

Comment: What prevents you to open */dev/driX* instead?

Comment: To handle the vblank interrupt, fbdev driver dont allow to do it